# Proof verification for $a = \sup A$

Tags: real-analysis

Q: Given $a$ is upper bound for set $A$ and also $a\in A$, then $a= \sup A$

Now assume that d is another upper bound for A.To prove that $a\leq d$. Assume that $a>d $. since $a\in A$, so this contradicts that d is upper bound for A. Hence $a>d$ is wrong.

Another proof :

Assume 1. $a >\ Sup A$. since $a\in A$ so this contradicts that Sup A definiton

2. Assume $a < \sup A$. Take $\epsilon= \ supA-1$. so now we have $\exists a\in A (a > sup A - \epsilon).$ so $ \exists a \in A (a > a) $ which is contradiction

Comment: “To prove that $a\leqslant d$.” is not a sentence.

Comment: @Sophie Clad   Correct . Alt: To prove $a=sup(A) $ , choose any $b<a$ and show $b$ can't be an upper bound of $A$ i.e $\exists c\in A $ such that $b<c\le a $. This is clear as $  c=a$ is a trivial choice.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos i don't understand

Comment: @SuccessfulFailure pls check alternate proof

Comment: What is there the understand? I just wrote that “To prove that $a\leqslant d$.” is not a sentence. And it isn't.

Comment: A supremum by definition is the least upper bound . Two important word "least" and "upper bound". Hence to prove a real number $\lambda$  is the supremum of  $A$  choose any real number $\mu< \lambda$ and  show $\mu$ can't be an upper bound of $A$ i.e you can always have an element $a\in A$ such that $\mu<a$. Alternatively, you can show any upper bound $\mu$ of $A$ satisfy $\lambda\le \mu$

Answer (score 1):

A direct proof is preferable if one is possible. Your argument is correct. Note that $a\leqslant \sup A\leqslant a$. First inequality due to $a\in A$. Second inequality by definition of supremum.

Comment: i have added another proof. kindly check

Comment: i dont understand second inequality